# Execute Stored Procedure on every month-end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a stored procedure where data with-in a particular data range will be extracted and dump into a temp table. I want this procedure to be called by running a .bat file and prompt user to input From and To dates. Any approach I can use?

Comment: Use SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 1):

Is it important which user executed that procedure ? If it is not you can create  scheduled Sql Server agent job.